# Trying to get DNS services running on Windows Server 2008 R2, what am I getting wrong?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, tcpip

Ok, So I am basically trying to get a home server pc up that will provide Domain name services, act as Mail server and web server. I have one static IP, well it's not officially static but hasn't changed in two years so I'll call it static.

I have done the following:

1. Configured router NAT/virtual port forward UDP/TCP port 53
   to the internal IP of my server 192.168.1.16, in adapter settings
   specified the manual settings: 192.168.1.16 IP, gateway 192.168.1.1, Subnet: 255.255.255.0
   and loopback DNS: 127.0.0.1
2. Using my public my public IP Checked using http://www.canyouseeme.org/
   that port 53 is open and is not being blocked by my ISP. It can see services on this port.
3. Registered Domain name (mydomain.com.au)
4. Updated whois database through the domain registrars site and registered NameServer names:
   ns0.mydomain.com.au and ns2.mydomain.com.au, both have been associated
   with my single public IP. (Waited 24 hours)
5. Update the nameserver for mydomain.com.au: primary ns0.mydomain.com.au secondary: ns2.mydomain.com.au
   (waited 24+ hours)
6. Installed Server 2008 R2, install web server role and DNS role.
   Webserver works when I enter my public IP into browser of any PC/mobile, get IIS7 welcome page.

In DNS server:

Created new forward lookup zone:

```
    ;
;  Database file mydoman.com.au.dns for mydomain.com.au zone.
;      Zone version:  10
;

@                       IN  SOA mydomain.com.au. mydomain.testdomain.com. (
                                10           ; serial number
                                900          ; refresh
                                600          ; retry
                                86400        ; expire
                                3600       ) ; default TTL

;
;  Zone NS records
;

@                       NS  ns0.mydomain.com.au.
@                       NS  ns1.mydomain.com.au.

;
;  Zone records
;

@                       A   192.168.1.16
www                     A   192.168.1.16
```

The Domain name services will however not work, the whois database updated with ns0.mydomain.com.au etc. but when I type in my site name www.mydomain.com.au from an external machine it will not open site and I can't even ping it (Can't find host)

When I check the ns0.mydomain.com.au NS record using a
tool Like: http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/

I get:

```
Security: Server ns0.mydomain.com.au (XXX.XXX.XXX.XX <- my public IP) is recursive
Domain exists but there is no such record
```

Any ideas, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(...shouldn't the @ & www records point to your public IP..?)

Is the DNS server actually running and servicing queries?  If your server is in a domain the service will need to be 'authorised' (right click on it in the MMC -> 'Authorise') before it will start working properly.  Is it answering local queries?  Is it allowed out via NAT at your router and are DNS responses allowed back in?

Is your file being recognised properly?  Are the records showing up in the MMC GUI?